# How to create correct MySQL query INSERT

Tags: mysql, insert

i have some data in the MySQL table like this:

```
2017-02-01: 'A': 'K1': 100
2017-02-01: 'A': 'K2': 200
2017-02-01: 'B': 'K1': 300
2017-02-02: 'A': 'K1': 110
2017-02-02: 'A': 'K2': 210
2017-02-02: 'B': 'K1': 310
```

i need to insert new data only if last (by date) value is not equal with new.
for example: `insert new 400 if last [A:K1]<>400`

i use 2 queries now for this job, but it's very slow to insert it:

```
$res=mysql_query("select * from `table` where `col1`='A' and `col2`='K1' order by 'date' desc limit 1");
$tkol=0;
if($res){while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){$tkol=$r[0]['col3']; break;}}
if($tkol!=$newVal){
$q="INSERT INTO `table` (`date`,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) VALUES ('2017-02-10','A','K1',$newVal)";
mysql_query($q);
}
```

how to write my task in 1 mysql-query like `"INSERT ... IF ..."`?
**Please, help me**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `INSERT INTO SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`date`,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`)
SELECT DISTINCT '2017-02-10', 'A', 'K1', $newVal
FROM `table` t1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(`date`) AS maxdate, `col1`, `col2`
    FROM `table` 
    WHERE `col1` = 'A'
    AND `col2` = 'K1'
) t2 ON t1.`col1` = t2.`col1` AND t1.`col2` = t2.`col2` AND t1.`date` = t2.`maxdate`
WHERE t1.`col1` = 'A'
AND t1.`col2` = 'K1'
AND t1.`col3` <> $newVal
```

Comment: Thanks my friend! It's working correct!!! I'm delighted! Thank you for your help!

Comment: script with your query have a more time of execution. can you optimize more?

Answer (score 0):

use significant column as `unique key` and use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`.

OR

You can use `insert ... from select ... where oldval <> newval`;

select will not have "from" and values will be straightly written into it from webserver.

---

```
$q="INSERT INTO `table` (`date`,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) select ".$date.", ".$a.", ".$b.", ".$c." WHERE not exists (select 1 from `table` where col1 = $a ... and date = select(max) date from table)";
```

And, remember about input validation!

Comment: i can't setup this columns as unique. I have the 'id' unique column. Other columns can't be a unique.

Comment: Also, remember, that unique keys can hold more than one column!

Comment: So I asked to help me make a valid request

Comment: mysql return error in "WHERE not exists (select 1 from `table` where col1 = $a and col2=$b and date = select(max) date from table)"